# Moving view from project created without storyboards to project with storyboards

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, tapku

I've searched for the answer to this but I am unable to find one
(or unable to understand the answers as I'm new to iOS)

I have a project created with storyboards. I would like to add
a particular view from a completely different project (that only uses code)
to my project and be able to alter it with the interface builder.

Is this possible?

Specifically, I am trying to add a tapku calendar to my project.
Maybe there is a workaround if the above is not an option.

Comment: U cant alter or view the UI design with code in IB

Comment: So, I suppose another question is, if I add the view to my project, how can I push from a storyboard view to the code-only view without affecting the rest of the story board? I've tried adding a view via storyboards and setting its file owner to the code-only view but this does not work.

Comment: if u want to design a separate view better use xib file instead of story board. it always easy to maintain a view and its file-owner.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the example Tapku, specifically the section on the monthly calendar, as you can see, you have to create a class that inherits from TKCalendarMonthTableViewController. Copy the example. 
To add it to your storyboard, add a UIViewController, and you assign the class you just created. 
This you can show UIViewController within another UIViewController by ConainerView, which I think is what you want